# Multiplying fractions and whole numbers

Tags: decimal-expansion

Why does multiplying  numbers less than 1 with fractional parts take away from whole number term and make the operation seem like a subtraction or division

```
e.g
0.25*1000 = 250 // same as 1000/4 or 1000-750
```

A strange thing to beginner mathematicians

Answer (score 1):

It's because it is like that $$0.25=\frac{25}{100}=\frac14$$
So$$\frac{1}{4}\cdot1000=\frac{1000}{4}=250$$
And it is $$1000-750=250$$
because we want to take $\frac14$ of something which is the same as taking the whole thing and removing $\frac34$ of it....
id est $$\frac14=1-\frac34$$
So the equation is basically both sides multiplied by $1000$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\;0.25=\frac{1}{4}\,$ so $\,0.25 \cdot 1000 = \bbox[border:1px solid black]{\cfrac{1000}{4}}=\cfrac{1000\cdot (4-3)}{4}=\cfrac{4000}{4}-\cfrac{3000}{4}=\bbox[border:1px solid black]{1000-750}$

Comment: May be this has roots in number theory and bases

Comment: why is 0.25 == 1/4

Comment: @CholthiPaulTtiopic: Because $4 \cdot 0.25 = 1$.